# Task Runner Explorer throws error with garbage characters

Tags: visual-studio, webpack, task-runner-explorer

When I try to run the Webpack Task Runner from the explorer, will error out with a bunch of garbage text (preventing me from troubleshooting).
When ran from console OR from NPM Task Runner Explorer (through the package.json scripts section) the tasks run without error.

output looks like:
[image]

I am afraid that there is some issue with Locale or language... but not sure and changing those would be too painful (other applications require Japanese system language).

System info:

- Windows 10 (anniversary update): language Japanese
- VS 2015 Pro (update 3) : language English
- Node.js (4.3.0)

Order of External Web Tools has $(PATH), c:\Program Files/nodejs, $(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External and $(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External\git